# How do I define a global variable in React Native?

Tags: javascript, variables, react-native, react-navigation

**Problem**
I am creating an app with React Native and firebase. I am using two tabs, and I want to pass the key from inside one tab to another tab (using `tabNavigator`/`reactNavigation` for the tabs). I don't know how to define a global variable. I did some reaserch and figured out that I needed to use some sort of `.global` command. I've tried using:

```
var passKey = '';
global.passKey = key; //defined before any screens
```

and when that didn't work:

```
this.global.setState({ passKey: item.key }) //defined in button in a flatlist
```

The statement `this.global.setState({})` gives me an error, and `global.passKey` might save the variable globally, but when I change the variable inside of the screens, one variable doesn't pass over to the other screen. I would really love some help getting a solution to passing a variable between two tabs. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if it's just a static variable that doesn't change over time, create a `constants.js` file somewhere in your project and do `export const MY_VARIABLE = 'theValue'`. After that you can import it into the file which needs it - `import { MY_VARIABLE } from './constants'`

Comment: since I can't predict what post the user is going to select, the variable would have to be edited. Is there any way to use your solution (because the code worked, just not for what I needed) but also edit the variable?

Comment: ok, I'm afraid I lack details on the task, but I think what you are trying to do is pass a parameter from one scene to another. There is actually no need to keep a global variable for that, you can pass parameters via `reactNavigation`. Does this link cover what you need? - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/basic-app#Passing-params

Comment: so let's say a user selects some post and is to be taken to another tab, you can do `navigate('AnotherTab', { postId: 'someId' })`, and access the parameter in your other tab. I assume this might be what you actually need

Comment: I know this question is really old, but I need help on an error I'm getting with parameters. Whenever I try to use parameters in a function, I get the error "can't find variable params." How do I use parameters inside functions? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It works this way:

### global.js

```js
export default {};
```

### Usage

```js
import global from './global';

global.passKey = 123;
```

Although you made your choice of accepted answer, I believe this is what you need.

Comment: thanks, I'll keep that in mind if the other solution ever doesn't work for me.

Comment: is it possible to update `passkey` in the code? i mean some thing like `global.passKey = 456;`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use redux, if you want to get your variable in two tabs. But if you dont use it before it can be a little complicated when you first start check the docs here https://redux.js.org/